# Undefined is not object(evaluating 'NativeModules.RNSearchBarManager.ComponentHeight')

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reactive-programming

When i use library search bar in link https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar => I have met this error, anyone has met this error can help me, solve this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on the screenshot you have attached (I moved it from your deleted answer to your question), I believe you are using Android.

I consulted the source code of the [library on GitHub](https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar), it would seem that this is designed for iOS and doesn't support Android, at least not at the moment.

It seems be getting `undefined` when evaluating [`style={{height: NativeModules.RNSearchBarManager.ComponentHeight}}`](https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar/blob/master/SearchBar.coffee#L61)
  but that value isn't available when running on Android. There are only [iOS native modules](https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar/blob/master/RNSearchBarManager.m) in this library at the time being.

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using is only for IOS. Try using this one instead.
[react native elements SearchBar](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html)